# Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2 VMWare on Ubuntu 18.04 host doesn't recognize iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, macos, ubuntu, usb, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 host with VMWare Workstation 15 Player Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2 as guest. I installed VMWare tools. My USB config is USB2.0, all three options is selected. I can see iPhone inside Mac OS System Report->USB, but Finder and Xcode cannot see iPhone. Host can successfully see it, if I disconnect. What may be the problem?
P.S. Used solution with `usb.quirks.device0 = "0x05ac:0x12a8 skip-reset, skip-refresh, skip-setconfig"`, doesn't help.